# How old was the Prophet Eliyahu when he was taken to Paradise?

Tags: age, eliyahu-hanavi

How old was Eliyahu when he was taken to Paradise?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Timeline of Jewish History](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3915966/jewish/Timeline-of-Jewish-History.htm#q6) Eliyahu Hanavi went up in the chariot in the year 3043 AM (which is 718 before the secular dating). However, the Tanach does not specify when he was born. There are those who say that he was the same as Pinchas. Pinchas was born before Aharon became Kohen Gadol. If we assume that he was bar mitzvah at the time of Yetzias Mitzraim (2448) then he would have been (3843-2435) 408 years old at the time of the ascension. However, we do not know exactly when he was born.

Comment: the Jewish Timeline Encyclopedia agrees on 3043 and makes a note that Eliyahu's mentor (by 2964) was Achiya Hashiloni who was born before Amram died (no later than 2392).

Comment: @rosends See Seder Hadoros (2990) and (3016).

Comment: @sabbahillel That tradition means Eliyahu HaNavi is an incarnation of Pinchas, who preceded him. And they both are incarnations from one of the angels, like is explained in Sefer Brit Menucha. All of this (the different types of incarnations of the soul) relates to the subject of "zivug" and "ibbur". It isn't to be taken in a plain chronological sense.